# Get advertising id in ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, tvos, google-advertising-id

I can't get advertisingId on tvOS. I've tried [react-native-advertising-id](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-advertising-id) although I'm using typescript, and this lib other than not working, does not suit me because of lack of typing.

Then I switched to [react-native-idfa-aaid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sparkfabrik/react-native-idfa-aaid) which works pretty well until I run it on tvOS... This is the error I'm getting.

`null is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeIdfaAaid.default.getAdvertisingInfo')`

It works good on android phone emulators and iOS phone emulators.
Yes I can see in the lib description that it supports android/ios, not tvOS specified, yet I couldn't find anything that would explicitly support all of those platforms.

This is the code:

```
ReactNativeIdfaAaid.getAdvertisingInfo().then((res: AdvertisingInfoResponse) => {
if (res.isAdTrackingLimited) {
  return {
    id: '',
    type,
  };
}
return {
  id: res.id!,
  type,
};
}).catch(console.error);
```

Any help with getting advertisingId crossplatform using just reactNative would be appreciated.

Comment: `react-native-idfa-aaid` supports Android and iOS according to its README file. There is no mention of tvOS.

Comment: Would be great if you'd read the question before answering it!

"Yes I can see in the lib description that it supports android/ios, not tvOS specified, yet I couldn't find anything that would explicitly support all of those platforms." and then "Any help with getting advertisingId crossplatform using just reactNative would be appreciated."

Comment: Ouch, I didn't see that...

Answer (score 1):

Ended up writing my own native module, any further info on package updates supporting tvOS will be appreciated!